# Get form fields by names or ids ASP .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have web form with some ids. also i have array of these names. and on submit i need to retrieve all these values by array of name.
Something like:

```
Request.Form["<some_name>"]
```

Problem in that ASP substitutes names with ctl00$MainContent$

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `ClientIDMode` to static and all your control id's will remain the same as they're rendered.

This will allow you to get them by their actual Id's.

Set this in the Page by adding the following...

```
<%@ Page ClientIDMode="Static" ...
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can also try this one.

```
 private void ChangeBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 foreach(Control c in Page.Controls)
 {
   if (c.Controls.Count > 0)
   {
     foreach(Control c2 in c.Controls)
     {
        if (c2.GetType().ToString() == "System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox")
        {
            myspan.InnerHtml = ((TextBox)c2).Text;
           ((TextBox)c2).Text = "";
        }
     }
  }
 }
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find any normal solution. For my purposes it is normal to use:

```
private string GetFieldValue(string fieldName)
{
    return Request.Form.Cast<string>()
        .Where(key => key.EndsWith(fieldName))
        .ToDictionary(key => key, key => Request.Form[key])
        .Values.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do some thing like this.

```
   var item = from key in Request.Form.AllKeys
                               where key.Contains(fieldname)
                               select Request.Form[key];
```